# Exemplification in special function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces

this question have 3 sections that are together.

> $ a)$ Give an example of a map that is open but not closed, and an example of a map that is closed but not open.
>
> $b)$Determine whether the projection map $\Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R$ sending $(x,y)$ to $x$is open or closed.
>
> $c)$ Do the same for map $f:\Bbb R \rightarrow S^1 , f(x)=(\cos x , \sin x)$

A map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is said to be open if $f(O)$ is open in $Y$ whenever $O$ is open in $X$. Similarly, $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is said to be closed if $f(C)$ is closed in $Y$ whenever $C$ is closed in $X$.

in this statement $S^1$ is the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ in $\Bbb R^2$ .

**My Thoughts:**

about statement $a)$ this statement is the inverse condition similarly continuous map.
in fact in continuous map we have:

A map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is said to be open if $f^{-1}(O)$ is open in $Y$ whenever $O$ is open in $X$. Similarly, $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is said to be closed if $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $Y$ whenever $C$ is closed in $X$.

so I conclude we must Prove and Do exemplification: that $f^{-1}$ is continuous. but $f$ is not continuous .
is I am thinking true?

about statement $b)$ $x$ in $\Bbb R$ is open and close (i think) but $(x,y)$ in $\Bbb R^2$ is open then $f$ is open by this definition .

about statement $c)$ I know this function is not homeomorphic if we replace $\Bbb R$ with $[0,2 \pi)$ i.e. $f^{-1}$ is not continuous . so this function is not open and is not close!

**Is my thoughts true?**

Comment: So, any thoughts about any part of the question?

Comment: @GerryMyerson OK,Thanks

Comment: Concerning your approach to the first question, (you've edited twice since I started typing, so whether my comment will still apply is anybody's guess) $f^{-1}$ needn't even exist as a function; if it does exist, then, yes, its continuity is equivalent to $f$ being open, but $f$ being continuous has nothing to do with $f$ being closed. Better to think of some really simple examples of maps.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer I posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a partial answer, to get things started.

A constant map takes every set to a closed set (I'm assuming points are closed but not open, e.g., let the codomain be the reals with the usual topology), so it's closed but not open.

Let $A_n$, $n=1,2,\dots$, be the set of all points $(x,n)$ in ${\bf R}^2$ with $x$ between $1/n$ and $1-(1/n)$, and let $A$ be the union of all the $A_n$. Then $A$ is closed, but its projection onto the reals is the open interval $(0,1)$.